# Microsoft Visio 2016 - Delete Attributes from Entity in Crow's Foot DB Notation diagrams

Tags: visio

I'm new to Visio 2016, and building ERD diagrams in Crow's Foot Database Notation. I can't figure out how to correctly delete an attribute from an entity. I am only able to delete the text from the attribute field, but which leaves a blank space making the entity too large. How do I correctly delete the attribute to make that extra space go away at the bottom of the diagram?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out Visio is very touchy on exactly where you hover your mouse pointer when working with entity object attributes. In order to remove and entity's attribute you need to be hovering over the text that names the attribute, and then use the cut command to remove it. For me this is the "command X" button combination on my Mac, which should be "control X" on Windows. If you are even slightly off of the text, even if by a pixel, it will cut the entire entity out of the document, which was what was happening to me continuously. Part of the problem is that I have to use MS Visio 2016 through Citrix, which has a slight response delay for me, and was probably the cause of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that right clicking on the entity and selecting "show attribute types".
You can then click on the attribute type and it selects the whole row of the attribute, so you can hit the del.